# Family Website CMS

Tags: plugins, content-management-system

I am looking for a CMS that would be incredibly user-friendly and would have the following features:

- really simple message board (no login required)
- family tree
- story telling area
- photo section
- news section

Is there anything out there like this that is really easily configurable? I've already messed around with Mambo and Family Connects, but I didnt like either of those. In the past I've just programmed my own websites, for lack of easily implementable features. However, I've assuming there's something I need out there just like this, that I can't find. Thanks.

---

I don't want anyone to have to login, for one. The is for a family website, and much of my family really don't know what a website is, let alone how to use one. I want a super simple website with huge buttons and not a whole lot of distractions. Family Connects is a good example of what I want, except the photo album is horrible. I want people to post messages without logging in or signing up, and haven't seen that ability in mambo sites I've looked at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using http://www.myfamily.com/ and it fits all my needs. It includes:

- Pictures (with option to order prints)
- Discussion
- Family Trees (free from ancestry.com)
- Videos
- Files
- Events

Answer (score 4):

I can understand your stipulation that your users (family) shouldn't have to sign up - but without a sign-in, your site will be a free-for-all for spammers, hackers and other bored Internet denizens.

That said, my suggestion is to use WordPress for a front end - register your family members yourself, and use a very basic template - or better yet, create one.

Comment: If it's on your own internal network and not exposed to the outside world, there's no need for a password.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a CMS for exactly what you are looking for.  My family uses it all the time and the majority of them are not computer savy.  The only downside is that it requires a login, but like other people have said, their really isn't a way around that if you want your information to be private.

Anyway, if you are still looking, try http://www.familycms.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've setup [CMS Made Simple](http://www.cmsmadesimple.org/) a couple times now. It's all PHP and you can edit it to your heart's content. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

CMS made simple seems to die according to this study about [content management systems found on MytestBox.com](http://www.mytestbox.com/content-management-software-reviews/content-management-systems-cms-market-share-survey-study-2008/)

But if it's just for a family website...
maybe you can try other CMSs which any web hosting company provides (like Joomla or Wordpress). 
These can be installed in several clicks (especially Wordpress - you can build a good site in Wordpress and it's very easy to maintain it).

For a family website I thiknk Wordpress is the best and enough (lots of plugins and skins can be found for it on the web.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for a family website you do have the option of removing the usernames/passwords/accounts by setting it up as an intranet site. Then you can browse it at home or from selective addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend geni.com.  It's much better than Myfamily.com